# Why Firebase Realtime Database onChildChanged is triggered when new descendant node is added to the node which being listened?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 instances of my app running on 2 devices.
Both devices are listening to the same DB node changes using `onChildChanged` method.
When new child node is added to the listened node the `onChildChanged` event only triggered on the same device that did this new node adding.
On the second device the `onChildChanged` event is not triggered for some reason.

But if I use `onChildAdded` method to be listened then this event `onChildAdded` is properly triggered on both devices when the node which changes we are listening gets updated by newly added child node.

I'm OK to accept that `onChildChanged` only triggered when any of descendant nodes actually get changed (not new child node added) on all devices. But why `onChildChanged` is only triggered on that device which performed new node adding?

So in short the question is:
Why when on device A new child node added into DB the `onChildAdded` triggered on both A and B devices and `onChildChanged` only triggered on device A (and not on B)?

Related docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener

**Update:**

I discovered that ServerValue.timestamp causes this behavior.
Without ServerValue.timestamp when we add new child node and listening for parent node changes the onChildChanged event has never triggered.
Only if we use ServerValue.timestamp as one of the fields of newly added child node the onChildChanged event happens BUT only on the device which added this new child node with server timestamp value.
I understand it most likely triggered because first the new child node is created with timestamp field placeholder and then this node is updated by server when real timestamp is written into required field.
So now the question is: **why not all devices with this application instances get the onChildChanged event in case we use ServerValue.timestamp?**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  final String dbDataPath = 'root/chatroom0001/messages';
  DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference ();
  StreamSubscription <Event> _messagesChangedSubscription;
  List <String> _lMessages = List <String> ();

  Future <List <String>> fetchMessages (String dbDataPath) async {
    List <String> lMessages = List <String> ();
    final DataSnapshot dataMessages = await dbRef.child (dbDataPath).once ();

    dataMessages.value.forEach ((k, v) => {
      lMessages.add (v ['message'])
    });

    return lMessages;
  }

  @override
  void initState () {
    super.initState ();

    DatabaseReference messagesRef = dbRef.child (dbDataPath);

    fetchMessages (dbDataPath).then ((lMessages) {
      _lMessages = lMessages;
      setState (() {});
    });

    _messagesChangedSubscription = dbRef.child (dbDataPath).onChildChanged.listen ((event) {
      fetchMessages (dbDataPath).then ((lMessages) {
        _lMessages = lMessages;
        setState (() {});
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose () {
    super.dispose ();

    _messagesChangedSubscription.cancel ();
  }

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (      
      body: Container (
        color: Colors.red, child: ListView.builder (
          itemCount: _lMessages.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return Container (padding: EdgeInsets.all (5), child: Text (_lMessages [i], style: TextStyle (fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0)));
          }
        )
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton (
        onPressed: () {
          DatabaseReference messagesRef = dbRef.child (dbDataPath);
          DatabaseReference newChatMessageRef = messagesRef.push ();
          newChatMessageRef.set ({
            'message': 'Hello Google!',
            'date': ServerValue.timestamp
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is test project source code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j3eHbD_3UxOhWWmZRfSoKqa-r9dyEwbV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The `onChildChanged` event fires for a child node that is changed, and in my experience has always behaved as expected. If that doesn't seem to be happening for you, edit your question to show the minimal code with which any of us can reproduce that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I discovered that this caused by ServerValue.timestamp.
Please take look this short video where I'm explaining the problem:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F9pkrm2OpWqLAg1eTI-Xjkynztb2SwtF/view?usp=sharing
I also update question description with new info.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please use this link do download source code of the project which reproduces the situation described:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j3eHbD_3UxOhWWmZRfSoKqa-r9dyEwbV/view?usp=sharing
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry @hellobody, but on Stack Overflow it is required to include the minimum code that reproduces the problem in the question itself. Links to outside resources tend to get outdated, and typically lead to way too much data. Since you've discovered the cause, can you edit your question to include the code that shows the problem? Note that code and logging output are much more likely to get your an answer, than a written description of the problem.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just added source code. Could you please take a look now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
  DatabaseReference newChatMessageRef = messagesRef.push ();
  newChatMessageRef.set ({
    'message': 'Hello Google!',
    'date': ServerValue.timestamp
  });
```

Will lead to two write events on the client that makes the change:

1. The local estimate fires a local event immediately when this code executes.
2. Then when the client receives the actual value from the server, it will fire another event for the final value.

Remote clients listening to this same node, will only see the second event. That can either be a `onValue` event, or an `onChildAdded` or `onChildChanged` event, depending on the type of listener used and the local state.

So on the client making the change: if you use a `onValue` listener, you'll see two value events, while if you use `onChild` listeners on the parent node, you'll see an `onChildAdded` for the local event, and then a `onChildChanged` for the final value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have some questions:
1. What is "local estimate"?
2. You wrote that "Remote clients listening to this same node, will only see the second event." And later you said that onChildChanged is a second event. But remote clients in my test case doesn't get onChildChanged.

Comment: 1) The client estimates what the timestamp timestamp is roughly going to be on the server, based on  local time and its last known offset between the local client and the server, 2) Correct, the `onChildAdded` and `onChildChanged` are local interpretations of the data at the node vs its previously known value. So for the remote clients the value they get (which is from step #2) is going to be an `onChildAdded` in your scenario if the client has never seen a child value before for that key.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks. The only confusing thing is that you call `onChildChanged` - **first** event, and `onChildAdded` - **second** event. What doesn't seem to be true. Just tested under debug: Actually **first happens** `onChildAdded` and then `onChildChanged`. So remote clients only see **FIRST** event `onChildAdded` with already applied final timestamp from server. And only the client which actually initiated data change after `onChildAdded` also gets `onChildChanged`. If I'm correct in my understanding now and you agree then we have to fix this "...will only see the second event".